# "Estimado Equipo de (nombre de la empresa)", ¿es correcto?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, formalidad, uso-de-mayúsculas, correspondencia

¿Está bien encabezar una carta de presentación con lo siguiente?

> Estimado equipo de (nombre de la empresa)

Es que eso es bueno en inglés.

Además, "equipo" debe ir con minúscula inicial, ¿no?

Comment: En mi empresa son más secos, aquí usan "A todo el personal", o a veces "Estimados todos". :-D Y sí, "equipo" tendría que escribirse en minúscula.

Comment: Muchas gracias. :) ¿Pero Estimado equipo de X está bien también?

Comment: Te expongo mi opinión en una respuesta aparte. Creo que esta pregunta puede ser más interesante de lo que aparenta, dadas las sutiles diferencias entre las definiciones de "team" en inglés y de "equipo" en español.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> <sup>**Descargo de responsabilidad:** Esta respuesta está basada en mi interpretación del idioma y por tanto aplica al español de España.</sup>

Supongamos por un momento que la empresa es [ACME](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporaci%C3%B3n_Acme). La carta empezaría tal que así (por supuesto, usando "equipo" con "e" minúscula al ser un sustantivo común):

```
Estimado equipo de ACME:

    Es para mí un motivo de orgullo y satisfacción...
```

En principio me suena raro, porque la palabra "equipo" la asocio a otras cosas. Por ejemplo, un equipo de fútbol, o de baloncesto, o en general un equipo de trabajo (asociado a un proyecto dentro de una empresa). Esto se debe a las acepciones de la propia palabra *[equipo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G09HIAP)*:

> 1. m. Grupo de personas organizado para una investigación o servicio determinados.
> 2. m. En ciertos deportes, cada uno de los grupos que se disputan el triunfo.

En el caso que mencionas, yo usaría otra palabra:

> **[personal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sjasuhi)**
>
> 4. m. Conjunto de las personas que trabajan en un mismo organismo, dependencia, fábrica, taller, etc.

En ese caso la carta sería así:

```
Estimado personal de ACME:

    Es para mí un motivo de orgullo y satisfacción...
```

Lo único malo es que la palabra "personal" es bastante aséptica, y la palabra "equipo" tiene una connotación de gente que trabaja junta, como parte de una máquina, en colaboración, y por tanto está bastante de moda hoy día. Entiendo pues que en las comunicaciones inter-empresa se usen palabras que fomenten ese espíritu.

Fíjate además que es curioso que la definición inglesa de *team* es:

> a number of persons associated together in work or activity

y por tanto se puede usar también en ámbitos laborales (*work*), mientras que la definición española habla de "investigación" o "servicio", no de "trabajo".

Te pongo un ejemplo de por qué me suena raro. Si hablamos de equipos de fútbol, si hablo de "el equipo del Betis" pienso en los jugadores designados por el Betis para jugar un partido de fútbol, pero en el Betis trabaja mucha más gente (y por eso se habla, además, de "el equipo técnico", "el equipo directivo" y demás). Si te fijas, se habla de "equipo" para hablar de un grupo de personas con una función concreta dentro de la empresa. Por tanto, si hablo de "el equipo de ACME" puedo pensar que se trata de un grupo elegido dentro del personal de ACME, seleccionado para una tarea concreta. Vería bien la expresión si ese grupo seleccionado se trasladara a trabajar a otra empresa como personal externo, entonces "el equipo de ACME" sería "el grupo de trabajadores que nos ha mandado ACME a trabajar aquí".

Resumiendo: no creo que el uso sea incorrecto, y menos teniendo en cuenta lo dicho sobre fomentar el espíritu de equipo entre los trabajadores, pero aun así no puedo evitar que me suene un poco rara la expresión. Tal vez solo sea cuestión de acostumbrarse.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Carlos, por tu respuesta detallada e informativa. Aprecio mucho tu tiempo. No voy a usar equipo entonces. jaja Yo sólo quería individuar la carta, porque así recomiendan los especialistas en recursos humanos etc. Pero bueno. Hasta que esa idea se globalice, voy a quedarme con las opciones tradicionales; trataré de elegir la opción más amable. :D
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra que pudiera corresponde al anglicismo es colegas o compañeros, dependiendo de si el remitente es o no miembro de la empresa

Comment: Muchas gracias.